# Using CLI C++ dll with /MDd CRT in a native c++ exe with /MTd CRT

Tags: c++-cli, msvcrt, crt

I have a native c++ exe using the /MTd runtime library. I cannot change this option as I dont have much control over the build of this exe. I need to call a CLI C++ dll in this exe which returns a class with STL vector member variables. At the return of the CLI C++ method, I get a heap corruption error. From my analysis, this happens because there are two different CRTs and the vectors deallocate method is running in the native CRT and bombs due to invalid address.

How do I return a vector from a CLI C++ dll which is compiled with a different CRT to run with my native exe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assessment is correct -- allocations performed inside one CRT cannot be deallocated inside a different CRT. It's a simple rule, and there's no way around it.

You need to build both modules with the same runtime library settings, or you need to transfer  only POD-types between module boundaries.

Comment: Bad news is not often appreciated.

Comment: I'm not going to submit this as an answer, but if you were desperate AND the class was returned by pointer rather than by value, AND you were certain to only call this method a few times during program execution, THEN you could simply not delete the the class.  It would leak, but perhaps that's acceptable.  The real answer is clearly to fix your application configuration, as @ildjarn pointed out.  Additionally, there's no guarantee that the vector access operations will work across different CRT's in the future.

Comment: Thanks ildjarn and David for your responses. I have replaced vector by pointers now. Since I know the size, I am creating arrays of the original vector members and passing them across the dll boundary. Only now I need to BE VERY CAREFUL of freeing memory only where it is allocated.